# C++ and Python ZeroMQ 4.x PUB/SUB example does not work

Tags: python, c++, tcp, zeromq, pyzmq

I can only find old C++ source examples. Anyways, I did mine, based on them. Here's my publisher in python:

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5563")

while True:
    msg = "hello"
    socket.send_string(msg)
    print("sent "+ msg)
    sleep(5)
```

And here's the subscriber in C++:

```
void * ctx = zmq_ctx_new();
void * subscriber = zmq_socket(ctx, ZMQ_SUB);
// zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://*:5563");
   zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5563");
// zmq_setsockopt(subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", sizeof(""));

while (true) {
    zmq_msg_t msg;
    int rc;

    rc = zmq_msg_init( & msg);
    assert(rc == 0);
    std::cout << "waiting for message..." << std::endl;
    rc = zmq_msg_recv( & msg, subscriber, 0);
    assert(rc == 1);

    std::cout << "received: " << (char * ) zmq_msg_data( & msg) << std::endl;
    zmq_msg_close( & msg);
}
```

Initially, I tried `zmq_setsockopt( subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", sizeof("") );` but I guess I should receive everything if I don't set this, right? So I commented it.

When I run the code, I see "waiting for message..." forever.

I tried to listen to TCP traffic using **`tcpdump`**. Turns out that when the publisher is turned on, I see a lot of garbage on the `5563` port, and when I turn the publisher off, they stop. When I tried a `PUSH/PULL` scheme, I could see the plaintext message in `tcpdump`. (I tried pushing with nodejs and pulling with c++ and it worked).

What could I be doing wrong?

I tried different combinations of `.bind()`, `.connect()`, `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, but they won't work either.

**UPDATE**: I've just read that I must subscribe to something, so I did `zmq_setsockopt( subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, NULL, 0 );` to subscribe to everything but I still receive nothing

PyZMQ is in version 17.0.0.b3 and has ZeroMQ 4.2.3

C++ has ZeroMQ 4.2.2

**UPDATE 2:**

Updates both to 4.2.3, won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's me, the one that asked the question.

I manage to get working by **exchanging** `socket.bind("tcp://*:5563")` to `socket.connect("tcp://dns_address_of_my_dcker_container:5564")` **in python**,

and exchanging `zmq_connect(subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5563")` to `zmq_bind(subscriber, "tcp://*:5563")` **in C++**

The examples that I found online said that I should use `bind` for the publisher and `connect` for the subscriber, but it wouldn't work in any way for me. Do anyone have an idea why?

ZeroMQ documentation says the following:

> The zmq_bind() function binds the socket to a local endpoint and then
>   accepts incoming connections on that endpoint.
>
> The zmq_connect() function connects the socket to an endpoint and then
>   accepts incoming connections on that endpoint.

I don't have a clear idea of what changed, but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

> <sub>*"I guess I should receive everything if I don't set this, right?*"</sub>

<sub>No, this is not a correct assumption. You may like a [**collection** of my other ZeroMQ posts here, about a { plain-string | unicode | serialisation }-issues and the { performance- | traffic- }-impacts actual policy ( **`SUB`**-side topic-filter processing on early ZeroMQ versions, and/or the **`PUB`**-side processing for more recent ones ) **one may encounter in heterogeneous distributed-systems' design, using ZeroMQ.**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20topic-filter)</sub>

<sub>( Any other Scalable Formal Communication Archetype Pattern, like the observed  `PUSH/PULL`, does nothing with the subscription policy, so will work independently of the subscription-matching processing against a set topic-filter list. )</sub>

---

### Step 0: Test the sending-part RTO first, if it `.send()`-s anything at all:

Let's mock-up a fast pythonic receiver, to see, if the sender indeed sends anything down the lane:

```
import zmq

aContext = zmq.Context()                                          # .new Context
aSUB     = aContext.socket( zmq.SUB )                             # .new Socket
aSUB.connect( "tcp://127.0.0.1:5563" )                            # .connect
aSUB.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )                                  # .set ALWAYS!
aSUB.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )                              # .set T-filter

MASK = "INF: .recv()-ed this:[{0:}]\n:     waited {1: > 7d} [us]"
aClk = zmq.Stopwatch(); 

while True:
      try:
           aClk.start(); print MASK.format( aSUB.recv(),
                                            aClk.stop()
                                            )
      except ( KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit ):
           pass
           break
pass
aSUB.close()                                                     # .close ALWAYS!
aContext.term()                                                  # .term  ALWAYS!
```

This ought report whatever the **`PUB`**-sender is actually `.send()`-ing over the wire and also the actual message inter-arrival times ( in `[us]`, glad the ZeroMQ has included this tool for debugging and performance / latency tweaking  ).

If ACK-ed as you see the live **`INF:`**-messages actually ticking on screen, keep it running and it now makes sense to proceed to the next step.

---

### Step 1: Test the receiving-part code next:

```
#include <zmq.h>
void *aContext = zmq_ctx_new();        
void *aSUB     = zmq_socket(     aContext, ZMQ_SUB );               std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_ctx_new() done" << std::endl;
                 zmq_connect(    aSUB,    "tcp://127.0.0.1:5563" ); std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_connect() done" << std::endl;
                 zmq_setsockopt( aSUB,     ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );  std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_setsockopt( ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ... ) done" << std::endl;
                 zmq_setsockopt( aSUB,     ZMQ_LINGER,        0 );  std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_setsockopt( ZMQ_LINGER, ...    ) done" << std::endl;
int rc;
while (true) {
         zmq_msg_t       msg;                            /*       Create an empty ØMQ message */
    rc = zmq_msg_init  (&msg);          assert (rc ==  0 && "EXC: in zmq_msg_init() call" );
                                               std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_msg_init() done" << std::endl;
    rc = zmq_msg_recv  (&msg, aSUB, 0); assert (rc != -1 && "EXC: in zmq_msg_recv() call" );
                                               std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_msg_recv() done: received [" << (char * ) zmq_msg_data( &msg ) << "]" << std::endl;
         zmq_msg_close (&msg);                           /*       Release message */
                                               std::cout << "INF: .. zmq_msg_close()'d" << std::endl;
}
zmq_close(    aSUB );                          std::cout << "INF: .. aSUB was zmq_close()'d" << std::endl;
zmq_ctx_term( aContext );                      std::cout << "INF: .. aCTX was zmq_ctx_term()'d" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the return value for *`zmq_setsockopt()`*?

Then you should use **`""`** instead of a **`NULL`**, they are different.

```
zmq_setsockopt( subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0 );
```

As API defines:

> **Return value**
>
> The `zmq_setsockopt()` function shall return zero if successful. Otherwise it shall return -1 and set ***`errno`*** to one of the values defined below.
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

The correct recipe to run the PUB/SUB pattern (regardless of language) is:

## Pub

1. `socket(zmq.PUB)`
2. `bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")`
3. encoding (usually just encode() for strings but you can also compress() or dumps() for objects or even both) `encoded_topic = topic.encode()` `encoded_msg = msg.encode()`
4. `send_multipart([encoded_topic, encoded_msg])`

## Sub

1. `socket(zmq.SUB)`
2. `setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, topic.encode())`
3. `connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")`
4. `answer = recv_multipart()`
5. decode the answer `enc_topic, enc_msg = answer` `topic = enc_topic.decode()` `msg = enc_msg.decode()`

In general, steps Pub - 2 / Sub - 3 (ie bind/connect) and Pub - 3 / Sub -
 5 (ie encode/decode or dumps/loads) need to be complementary to each other in order for things to work.